# IConfiguration.GetSection() as Properties returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, as-operator

I'm trying to retrieve configuration inside my application.

I have passed the IConfiguration into the service class which needs to pull some settings.

The class looks a bit like this:

```
private IConfiguration _configuration;
public Config(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}
public POCO GetSettingsConfiguration()
{
    var section = _configuration.GetSection("settings") as POCO;

    return section;
}
```

In debug, I can see that _configuration does contain the settings
but my "section" is simply returned as null.

I'm aware that I could try to set up the Poco to be created in the startup, and then injected as a dependency, but due to the setup, I'd rather do it in separate classes from the injected IConfiguration, if possible.

My appsettings.json has these values:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "settings": {
    "Username": "user",
    "Password": "password",
    "Domain": "example.com",
    "URL": "http://service.example.com"
  }

}
```

My poco class looks like this:

```
public class POCO
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public SecureString Password { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Read up on the `as` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use:

```
var section = _configuration.GetSection("settings").Get<POCO>();
```

What's returned from `GetSection` is just a dictionary of strings. You cannot cast that to your POCO class.

Comment: I don't have an .Get option after GetSelection.

Comment: It's in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` namespace. I don't see how you do not already have a using for that, but if you don't, add one. Otherwise, there's something seriously wrong with your project.

Comment: Can confirm that its `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`. The class libary targets .net core 2.2

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. It's there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=aspnetcore-2.2. Make sure that your project is building correctly.

Comment: Okay, turns out I was missing the .Binding package. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting. That's not something you should need to explicitly reference. Should be covered in a reference to the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` package or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package.

Comment: Actually, looks like it's only included by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`. Are you using this in a class library or something? If it's an ASP.NET Core app, then you should only be referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

Comment: After adding the nuget package  `Microsoft.Extenions.Configurations.Binding` it worked

Comment: I know. My point is that unless you're doing this in a class library or some other project where you cannot reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage, that should not be necessary. If you have an ASP.NET Core web application project that is *not* referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, that is something you need to fix. (Unless you're targeting .NET Framework, in which case you have to reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` instead.)

Answer (score 6):

`IConfiguration` and `IConfigurationSection` have an extension method [Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_Bind_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_Object_) for this purpose:

```cs
var poco = new POCO();
_configuration.GetSection("settings").Bind(poco);
```

Or just [Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_Get_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_Type_)

```cs
var poco = _configuration.GetSection("settings").Get(typeof(POCO));
```

Or generic [Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_Get__1_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_)

```cs
var poco = _configuration.GetSection("settings").Get<POCO>();
```